# Does iOS distribution push notification need device token

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've used the following tutorial to implement push notification in my app.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

And it works for development version. But I had include a device token in the payload (php) file.

Does this need to be the same for distribution as well. Do I need to gather all the device tokens from active users and send distribution push notifications, one by one?

I thought I would be able to do a broadcast without keeping track of all active device tokens. Is this not the case?

App is already on app store by the way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to keep track of their device tokens. Also keep in mind that the device token might change for a single device, even though that doesn't happen frequently.

If you think that's too much trouble, you can use some service like Parse.com to do that for you, using their SDK.